# onUpdate() never triggers

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I'm writing a simple node app using firebase. It has a list of tasks that can be checked off by the user, which updates the database. I'm trying listen for changes on the database and update each checkbox when the boolean associated with it on the database is changed. However, the onUpdate never triggers.
 My database looks like this:

```
tasks
├── 0
|   ├── text: "task 1"
|   └── isDone: bool
├── 1
|   ├── text: "task 2"
|   └── isDone: bool
etc...
```

Here's my code for onUpdate:

```
const ref = functions.database.ref('tasks')
.onUpdate((snap, context) => {
    console.log("Updated!");
    snap.forEach(shot => {
        el = document.getElementById(shot.toString());
        el.checked = shot.isDone;
    });
})
```

(The ids of my checkboxes are numbered from 0)

Comment: You have `document.getElementById(shot.toString());` - are you running this within a browser environment or within a node.js program?

Comment: You typically don't use Cloud Functions to run code only locally.  Use the admin SDK for that, and skip Cloud Functions entirely.

Comment: You're right, I can't access the document from the node.js program. But shouldn't the function still trigger? I don't get an error, nor do I see "Updated!" in the console.

Comment: Try using `admin.database().ref("tasks").on('child_changed', function(snapshot) { ... })` - [documentation here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.database.Reference#on)

Comment: That did it for me. Thanks so much! If you want to post that as an answer, I'll mark it as such.